# fatal error in git push command

Tags: git, push, fatal-error

I am trying to push a change in Gerrit using the following command,

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/audi
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: One or more refs/for/ names blocks change upload
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried other solutions in SO and other sites but to no success like:

https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/error-change-upload-blocked.html

Command:

```
git for-each-ref refs/for
```

returns nothing.

Am stuck for an important software delivery to the client, please help.

**Note**: 
The response for git remote is as follows:

> git remote -v
>
> origin    ssh://14.140.172.187:29418/android_m/hlos/platform/build
>   (fetch)
>
> origin    ssh://14.140.172.187:29418/android_m/hlos/platform/build (push)

Comment: Why are you using that syntax for pushing?  Why not just `git push origin some_branch`?

Comment: the ptach should go to gerrit server for review and from it should be pushed. Note: i tried but same error message

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's Gerrit's syntax for commits that need review before being merged into the target branch.

Comment: What does `git fetch` return?

Comment: its returning nothing.

Answer (score 1):

While you may not have any local `refs/for` branches to delete (since you mention that the command `git for-each-ref refs/for` returns nothing), the [Gerrit documentation for that error message](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-change-upload-blocked.html) does stipulate:

> Branches under the '`refs/for/`' namespace can be created by users that bypass Gerrit and **push directly to the git repository itself (not using the Gerrit server’s SSH port)**.

So check first what origin is referring to (it should be the gerrit server), with `git remote -v`.
But check also the final repo which is proxied behing the Gerrit repo: this is where no `/refs/for` branch should be. It is in *that* remote repo you should delete any `refs/for` branches.

[image: https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.15.1/images/intro-quick-central-gerrit.png]

"That" repo means the "authoritative" repo.

If you have the right to push directly to that remote repo (again, not the Gerrit one, but the one Gerrit is supposed to push to), you need to delete those remote branches.
Clone that repo, apply the command mentioned in the doc:

```
for n in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/for);
    do git update-ref -d $n; done
```

Then push back with `git push --mirror`.

If you don't have the right to push to that remote client repo, contact the client and ask for the cleanup to be done in that target repo.

Comment: thanks, for megit remote -v
origin ssh://14.140.172.187:29418/android_m/hlos/platform/build (fetch)
origin ssh://14.140.172.187:29418/android_m/hlos/platform/build (push)

Comment: it shows no intermediate branches. Is it something related to access rights to repository? how can i verify if the access rights are correct for th euser?

Comment: @Anshul I am talking about the authorative repo, so not one you are referencing in your local machine through git remote, but one on the server side: you need to check for `refs/for` branches there, on that server, in that repo.

Comment: any idea how to do it.. we are using a bare repo to sync our code. Its on same server and accessible.

Comment: @Anshul Then to the bare repo folder, and do a git branch -avv in it.

Comment: thanks VonC,    at the bare repo the output to the command is                                   qc8939_audi_main e1c4b68  Changed the build ID to AUDI_M_R45.00.         ----------                                                                                        
qc8939_audi_india  1dec59c  Changed the build ID to AUDI_M_R45.00.  which is correct since we have only 2 branches

Comment: the name of two branches is qc8939_audi_main  and  qc8939_audi_india

Comment: So no refs/fo branches... can you check in any other bare repo that you have?

Comment: the same repo was working fine till last release 44(last week), no clue why it is misbehaving now. the only difference is that the user was deleted and created again.